# Undefined function or variable 'resubPredict'. Why?

Tags: matlab, classification, svm, confusion-matrix

I have MATLAB R2015b and I am working on a Pattern Recognition project. I have loaded fisher iris data set.
I have written the code below for k-NN classification:

```
rng default;
fold_number = 5;
indices = crossvalind('Kfold',species, fold_number);

val = 1:2:5; % for these small k values there will not be an important difference
         % regarding the cp ErrorRates. The difference is going to be
         % observable for val = 1:2:100, for example!!! But the
         % exercise asks only for k = 1,3,5.

err_arr = [];

for k=val

    cp = classperf(species); % Reinitialize the cp-structure!

    for i = 1:fold_number
        test = (indices == i); 
        train = ~test;
        class = knnclassify(meas(test,:),meas(train,:),species(train), k);
        %class = knnclassify(meas(test,2),meas(train,2),species(train), k); % To experiment only with the 2nd feature

        classperf(cp,class,test);
    end
    err_arr = [err_arr; cp.ErrorRate];
    fprintf('The k-NN classification error rate for k = %d is: %f\n', k,cp.ErrorRate);
end  

fprintf('\n The error array is: \n');
disp(err_arr);

fprintf('Program paused. Press enter to continue.\n');
pause
```

After that, I would like to plot the confusion matrix. So, I need this line of code:

```
[C,order] = confusionmat(species, predicted_species);
```

So, I have to find the predicted_species matrix. I have thought to write the below line of code about that:

```
predicted_species = resubPredict(class);
```

Here is the moment I am getting the on the title mentioned error and I do not know why, while resubPredict is a function supported by my MATLAB version.

Could anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide the *full* error message and stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the top of the documentation for `resubPredict`, there you will notice the line

> Class ClassificationKNN

Meaning that the function can only be used with inputs of that type. In your case you are passing doubles.

You have to switch to the new interface, [fitcknn instead of knnclassify](http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/knnclassify.html)

Comment: So, either I have to change my code using fiction or have to find another way to write resubPredict. (I think the latter is more likely to do.)